# script.aculo.us toggle appear on multiple div's

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle, scriptaculous

I got into a bit of a mess with my code and I hoped you guys could help me out with a clever idea.

So, I am working an a html page and using scriptaculous to make some div's appear and fade using the toggle effect. The things is, for this to work, you of course have to use style="display: none" in your div, but this creates an issue with my slideshow. Let me show you how it looks:

**- My menu**

```
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="Effect.toggle('aboutDiv', 'appear'); return false;"></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="Effect.toggle('missionDiv', 'appear'); return false;"></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="Effect.toggle('portfolioDiv', 'appear'); return false;"></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="Effect.toggle('contactDiv', 'appear'); return false;"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

**My divs**

```
<div id="portfolioDiv" style="display: none">
<a href="#" class="close" onclick="Effect.toggle('portfolioDiv', 'appear'); return false;">&#10006;</a>
    <!-- 630px X 430px -->
    <div id="slideDiv">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <img src="image/img1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li>
                <img src="image/img2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li>
                <img src="image/img1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li>
                <img src="image/img2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li>
                <img src="image/img1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li>
                <img src="image/img2.jpg" alt="" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**- CSS**

```
#portfolioDiv
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 700px;
    width: 430px;
    left: 3%;
    top: 16%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;      
}

#slideDiv
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 630px;
    width: 430px;
    top: 70px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

**- The problem**

*- I'm using Horinaja slideshow.*

When I use `style="display: none"` on the **portfolioDiv**, the slideshow does not work. When I use `style="display: none"` on my **slideDiv** it does. I can't seem to understand what's causing this issue.

**- Tried solution**

To try and fix this, I wanted to seperate the 2 divs (**portfolioDiv** and **slideDiv**) and then place them individually, instead of putting slideDiv within portfolioDiv, but then I need to using Effect.toggle with Effect.multiple in my menu with the onclick, but I was unable to do so, because I don't know how to basically.

*Hope you are able to help me somehow, thanks.*

Comment: I would like to add that I tried using the Effect.Opacity function, which worked to an extend. I was able to make everything work, but this effect doesn't allow toggle! Maybe something could be done here, to make it un-spammable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it be using:

```
<a href="#" onclick="Effect.multiple(['portfolioDiv','slideDiv'],function(el){Effect.toggle(el,'appear');});">
```